# What is the view of the Jews for the Messiah

Tags: messiah, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In the prophecies in Isaiah 9:6, in a modern version of the Authorized Version (a Christian translation):

> For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the
>   government shall be upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called
>   Wonderful, Counselor, The mighty God, The everlasting Father, The
>   Prince of Peace.

Based on this scripture text, his named will be called "The mighty God" is this English translation accurate to what the actual Hebrew text says? Or it should be:

> For a child is born unto us.  A son is given unto us; And the
>   government is upon his shoulder;   and  his   name   is   called
>   Pele-joez-el-gibbor-Abi-ad-sar-shalom."   (The Holy Scriptures
>   According to the Masoretic Text, 1917 edition)

The Hebrew name `Pele- joez-el-gibbor-abi-ad-sar-shalom` is translated as,

> Wonderful  in counsel is God the Mighty, the everlasting Father, the
>   Ruler of Peace.

**Update:**

What is the view of the Jews for the Messiah? Most Christian denominations today share the view of the Messiah as divine taking into account the passage above as their reference, however I am not sure if how the Jews view the Messiah, is it divine by nature?

Comment: "Teachings about the messiah" is pretty broad as a question.  Are you really asking how Judaism understands this particular passage?  If so, could you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I have updated the question

Comment: I'm afraid it's still unclear to me what you're asking; you start out asking about a passage in Isaiah (but starting from an untrustworthy translation), and end by asking "what is the view of the Jews for the messiah".  I'm going to put this on hold; please edit to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10599/472 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22271/472 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26938/472 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8857/472 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9754/472

Answer (score 2):

1) Here's is the commentary from [Rashi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashi):

> **For a child has been born to us:** Although Ahaz is wicked, his son who was born to him many years ago [nine years prior to his assuming
>   the throne] to be our king in his stead, shall be a righteous man, and
>   the authority of the Holy One, blessed be He, and His yoke shall be on
>   his shoulder, for he shall engage in the Torah and observe the
>   commandments, and he shall bend his shoulder to bear the burden of the
>   Holy One, blessed be He.
>   **and… called his name:** The Holy One, blessed be He, Who gives wondrous counsel, is a mighty God and an everlasting Father, called
>   Hezekiah’s name, “the prince of peace,” since peace and truth will be
>   in his days. (Transation from Chabad)

So "Peleh-yoetz-el-gibbor-Avi-ad" refers to God, and "Prince of Peace" refers to the name. You should be aware that Biblical Hebrew syntax allows for the subject to follow the verb, and vice-versa. (Though verb-subject is much more common.)

2) [Abraham_ibn_Ezra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ibn_Ezra) on the other hand, cites the opinion of Rashi and those who agree with him. But he prefers the explanation that all the names refer to the child, and he interprets each name as referring to various aspects of Hezekiah's personality and life. For example, "peleh"=פלא literally means "wonder" (It's a **noun**, and not the **adjective** "wonderful"- that would be "muflah"=מפלא or "niflah"=נפלא.) [David Kimhi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Kimhi) provides a similar explanation  and specifies that the wonder referred to are the events described in Kings II 20:9-11.

You'll find that many Hebrew names contains God's name. For example, "Elijah"=אליהו contains two Divine names. Another example is Genesis 22:14:

> And Abraham named that place, "The Lord will see"...